Как сделать свой класс, наследник от Form | C#, WinForms
У меня как бы получилось:
App.cs
internal class App : Form
{
    internal App()
    {
        TopLevel = false;
    }
}

WaveBrowser.cs
internal partial class WaveBrowser : App
{
    internal WaveBrowser() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Size = new Size(500, 300);
        Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "Button", Location = new Point(40, 40)});
    }
}

И оно корректно работает, но по какой-то причине, для WaveBrowser'a не открывается конструктор:


Конструтор сделайте public
